# How to create a textbox (from toolbox) in asp.net mvc2 web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, toolbox

The toolbox says there is no usable control in this group?

I have to create a textbox in asp.net mvc2 web application?

Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The toolbox is a habit that you might have learned from WebForms development but which no longer applies in ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC you write code. And to generate a textbox (`<input type="text" ...`) you could use the [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703644.aspx) HTML helper:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeViewModelProperty) %>
```

or if you don't have a strongly typed view (although you should if you want a properly designed MVC application)

```
<%= Html.TextBox("SomeViewModelProperty") %>
```

So say goodbye to server controls and toolboxes and say hello to [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: hello darin, i am new to asp.net mvc2. i am just creating sample programs. please tell me how do i get textbox and where do i type the html helper code

Comment: @software you may start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc. The site contains many tutorials and videos you might go through.